# Cannot delete folder in network drive in Windows 7 after using Cygwin

Tags: bash, windows-7, cygwin, network-drive

I'm using Windows 7 and have Cygwin installed on it. Using Cygwin, I recently tried to write a new file using Vim within a network drive. When trying to save it, Vim complained the file was read-only (`ls -la` showed that files on this drive had very few permissions, which seems odd as the permissions are a lot different if I try the same using Git Bash).

I forced Vim to write the file anyway, but after exiting the file wasn't present in either Windows explorer or any Unix shell. I then tried renaming the folder the files were kept in (`Includes` -> `IncludesOld`), creating a new folder with the original name and moving all the files to the new folder. This left the original folder (`IncludesOld`) empty, but I haven't been able to delete it. If I try to delete it, no error message appears, but the folder still remains.

I'm guessing this has something to do with Cygwin maintaining its own view of the file system which is inconsistent with the one I'm seeing, but I'm not sure what to do about that.

Running `mount` produces the following output:

```
C:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
B: on /cygdrive/b type udf (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
E: on /cygdrive/e type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
O: on /cygdrive/o type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
S: on /cygdrive/s type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
T: on /cygdrive/t type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
U: on /cygdrive/u type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
W: on /cygdrive/w type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
X: on /cygdrive/x type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

The folder in question is on the `W:` drive, but running `umount /cygdrive/w` gives me `umount: /cygdrive/w: Invalid argument`, and I'm only guessing that this is what I should be trying to do anyway.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, folders can easily be deleted using `rm -rf <folder name>`. If a problem appears, you can try `sudo chown <username:group> <folder name>` and run `rm -rf` again. If the problem persists, add to your question what `lsattr <folder name>` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you tried to delete `IncludesOld` using both cygwin as well as native windows methods. Since you mentioned that the directory is in a network mount, I would go to computer that hosts that folder and try to delete from there directly using the native method of the OS that is running in that machine. If that doesn't work, then I would check the disk volume for filesystem errors.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question almost two years so I'm going by memory here, but I *believe* that I managed to fix it by right-clicking the folder (`includesOld`) in Windows explorer and going to the "Security" tab. I vaguely remember something about not having all permissions and changing the security settings to give me full control. After that, I was able to delete it.